# logical mistake while checking integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was just writing a code to check whether a number is a perfect square and encountered an issue - the code is workin only for '4' , for example if entered number is 36, when i reaches the value 6, i**i is found to be 6*36- i mean i possesses different values there

```
n=int(input('Enter an integer '))
x=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if (i**i)==n:
        print('you entered a perfect square ',i,'^',i,'=',n)
    else:
        x=x+1
if x==n:
    print('you didnt enter a perfect square ')
```

**i dont want any edits to my logic - somebody pls improve the same code**

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `i**i` means `i^i`, but to check if the given number is a perfect square or not, you need to check `if i**2 == n`. With your logic, we don't need to check for numbers which are more than `sqrt(n)`. If you use a function, code will be much easier to debug. So an improved version will be:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_perf_sq(n):
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n))+1):
        if i**2 == n:
            return 'You entered a perfect square '+ str(i) + '^ 2 =' + str(n)
    return str(n) + ' is not a perfect square'

n = int(input('Enter an integer:').strip())
print(is_perf_sq(n))
```

*Run time improvement:*

You don't need to check for all number and square and check them, you just need the square root of that number. Then add `0.5` to it and square the integer part, if we get back the number then it's a perfect square otherwise not. So the code will be then:

```
from math import sqrt
n = int(input('Enter an integer:'))
if int(sqrt(n)+0.5)**2 == n:
    print(n, 'is a perfect square')
else:
    print(n, 'is not a perfect square')
```

Answer (score 2):

change the line

```
if (i**i)==n:
```

to

```
if (i*i) == n:
```